# Django prepopulate form in UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

Would like to know if it's possible to prepopulate my CommentForm in UpdateView. Updating comments work's except that the form is not loaded prepopulated.

When testing using a separate template it's loaded prepopulated, but I would like to use the same template (PostDetail) using a modal to update the comment.

views.py:

```
class PostDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, slug, pk, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset,slug=slug, pk=pk)
        comments = post.comments.order_by('-created_on')

        return render(
            request,
            'blog/post_detail.html',
            {
                'post': post,
                'comments': comments,
                'comment_form': CommentForm()
            },
        )

    def post(self, request, slug, pk, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            queryset = Post.objects.all()
            post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug, pk=pk)
            comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post
                comment.author = request.user
                comment.save()
                messages.info(request, 'Comment added')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[slug, pk]))


class CommentUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentForm
 
    def get_success_url(self):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.object.post.pk)
        messages.info(self.request, 'Comment updated')
        return post.get_absolute_url()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.author:
            return True
        return False`
```

forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

post_detail.html (form):

```
<form action="{% url 'comment_update' post.slug comment.pk %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ comment_form | crispy }}                         
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Update</button>
</form>
```

Please need help :)

I have tested adding:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['instance'] = self.get_object()
    return kwargs
```

The form is still not prepopulated. It works if I use a separate template and render the form using {{ form | crispy }}.

Perhaps it's because I have two {{ comment_form | crispy }} in my post_detail.html, one when creating the comment and one to update it?

I've spend alot of time trying to figure this out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass that instance of the `Comment` model which you'd like to update in `CommetForm`. In the `get_form_kwargs()` method, you can add the `instance` keyword argument to the form kwargs with the instance of the Comment model to update. Then, the `CommentForm` will be pre-populated with the data from that instance while displaying in frontend so:

```py
class CommentUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentForm
 
    def get_success_url(self):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.object.post.pk)
        messages.info(self.request, 'Comment updated')
        return post.get_absolute_url()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = self.get_object()
        return kwargs

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.author:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Dear, Sunderam Dubey 
I have tested and it did not work, maybe I did not understand you correct?
If you have time could you please help me?

Comment: @mr_bobby Did you receive any error?

Comment: @mr_bobby Can you share me the GitHub repo?